# SQLServer AlwaysOn and .net SqlConnection reset

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

In our enviroment we use SQLServer Always on cluster with two servers.

One of them is for write, second for reading. In application services `SqlConnection` opens and closes every second for short query execution. But after switching or turning off one of the servers in Always On cluster I began get an exceptions from my application services.

This tells that it can not insert any data in read only database. I suppose that main reason for this is connection pool inside SqlConnection implementation.

So the question is how to reset that connection pool manually. Or if there another kind of problem - let me know what do you think about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `MultiSubnetFailover = True` in connection string and implement retry logic:

> If a SqlClient application is connected to an AlwaysOn database that
>   fails over, the original connection is broken and the application must
>   open a new connection to continue work after the failover.

[SqlClient Support for High Availability, Disaster Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sqlclient-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery#connecting-with-multisubnetfailover)

Also:

> Setting MultiSubnetFailover to true isn't required with .NET Framework
>   4.6.1 or later versions.

Comment: The 'MultiSubnetFailover ' setting only ensures that .net will connect to both (or more) endpoints resolved by dns at once, and use the connection that replies first. The original problem is, that the connection is succeeded, but the server connected to is not the one running as primary for the current ag and database.

Comment: @Stephen Ryer: With AG's setting MultiSubnetFailover = True connect to the currently active server. I don't see that your statement: "The original problem is, that the connection is succeeded, but the server connected to is not the one running as primary for the current ag and database" is true.

Comment: I just ran som tests on an availability group in my alwayson setup. I connect, select servername and do a query to the database. When doing a failover, different scenarios occur, but one of the is, that selecting the servername succeeds (but reveals that the old primary is still the on connected to, and hence the qeury will fail when trying to access the actual database). So using MultiSubnetFailover will not cover this case - that was just my point.

Comment: "but reveals that the old primary is still the on connected to" - that seems unusual.